# Insert image files into SQL Server Table using a Loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to draft a SQL script that will loop to insert image files into a SQL Server table matching based on ID. I have named the image files based on the `customerID` I have in my database. I want to figure out a way to loop through the member ID's and insert the images into my table. Below is my current code.

```
Declare @CUSTCD int, @EVENTCD nvarchar(50), @SIGNATURES varbinary(max)    

SET @SIGNATURES = Select BulkColumn from Openrowset (Bulk 'C:\sigs\'+ @CUSTCD int+ '.png', Single_Blob) as Image


-- declare a cursor
DECLARE insert_cursor CURSOR FOR 
select @CUSTCD,'75thCelebration', BulkColumn from Openrowset (Bulk 'C:\sigs\'+(Select @CUSTCD from CUS)+'119.png', Single_Blob) as Image
--SELECT CUSTCD , EVENTCD, SIGNATURES  from CUS_SIGS2
--WHERE CUSTCD = 78

-- open cursor and fetch first row into variables
OPEN insert_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM insert_cursor into @CUSTCD, @EVENTCD, @SIGNATURES

-- check for a new row
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
-- do complex operation here
Insert into CUS_SIGS2   
SELECT @CUSTCD, @EVENTCD, @SIGNATURES
-- get next available row into variables
FETCH NEXT FROM insert_cursor into @CUSTCD, @EVENTCD, @SIGNATURES
END
close insert_cursor
Deallocate insert_cursor
GO
```

Comment: better to create a simple powershell script. Not recommended to access file system using xp_cmdshell due to security concerns.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is to use a [cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: would you be able to provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
Create table #tmp
(
    SalesOrderID int,
    OrderQty int
)
GO
--simple cursor in sql server 
Declare @orderid int, @orderqty int
-- declare a cursor
DECLARE insert_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT SalesOrderId,OrderQty from Sales.SalesOrderDetail
WHERE SalesOrderID=43659

-- open cursor and fetch first row into variables
OPEN insert_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM insert_cursor into @orderid,@orderqty

-- check for a new row
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
-- do complex operation here
Insert into #tmp
SELECT @orderid,@orderqty
-- get next available row into variables
FETCH NEXT FROM insert_cursor into @orderid,@orderqty 
END
close insert_cursor
Deallocate insert_cursor
GO
```